# JAVA: Serialization works good on Local Machine but when I do this in LAN it does not output correct

Tags: java, networking, serialization, client-server

**I want to send an object having OS Name to a server. This OS Name output should be of PC sending object but it displays OS Name of PC running server..**

Here is my code :

//Client : it can send data i.e. object to server
    class Client

```
{

        private Socket socket = null;


private ObjectOutputStream outputStream = null;

    public Client(String con){

System.out.println("conn value: "+con);

java.util.Timer t = new java.util.Timer();

try{

socket = new Socket(con, 27051);

t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

 @Override

    public void run() {

    try {

outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

SI sysinfo=new SI();

 outputStream.writeObject(sysinfo);

System.out.println("Sent Data: "+sysinfo.otherInfo());


}  catch (Exception se) {

   t.cancel();

}

 }
 },  0, 1);

}

catch(Exception em)

{

  }

}

}

//Server class: should receive data from client

class Server extends SwingWorker<Void,Void>{

   Socket csocket=null;  

        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {



        final ServerSocket ssock = new ServerSocket(27051);

System.out.println("Server Listening..!!");


      while (true) {

           try{

          Socket sock = ssock.accept();

         new Thread(new Server(sock)).start();

           }

           catch(Exception e){

               System.out.println("unabke to create socket");

           }

     }   


   }

      Server() throws Exception{

          doInBackground();

      }

   Server(Socket csocket) {

       this.csocket=csocket;

       Thread t1=new Thread(r1);

   t1.start();

   }

   Runnable r1=new Runnable()

   {

   public void run() {

     try {  

         System.out.println("Run initated");

          while(true)

       {


          if(csocket.isClosed())

          {

break;
          }


          else{

System.out.println(csocket);

    ObjectInputStream inStream = new 

ObjectInputStream(csocket.getInputStream());

SI sysinfo= (SI) inStream.readObject();


System.out.println("Received: "+sysinfo.otherInfo());

System.out.println(ObjectStreamClass.lookup(sysinfo.getClass()).getSerialVersion
UID());


   }
          }


      }

 catch (Exception e) {

System.out.println("Exception"+ e.getMessage());
       }

            }
   };

}
```

//class undergoing serialization

```
public class SI implements Serializable

{ 

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;     

String otherInfo()

{

 OperatingSystemMXBean bean = (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory
            .getOperatingSystemMXBean();



String os_name=bean.getName();

return os_name;  

}

}
```

//class A: It has main function and it executes first and user decides whether he/she want to be in server mode or in client mode. As user cannot be in 2 modes simultaneously..

```
class A

{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception

{

    System.out.println("Enter 0 for Server 1 for Client Mode");

Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

int i=s.nextInt();

if(i==0)

{

    Server ser=new Server();

ser.execute();

}

else if(i==1)

{

    System.out.println("Enter IP");

String conn=s.next();

Client c=new Client(conn);

}

else

    System.out.println("Invalid Selection exit..");

}

}
```

Comment: Clean up your sample code, because it is unreadable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You have posted way to much code in your question, which makes it unclear to us (and to future readers) exactly where the problem is.  Please reduce your problem code to 10 lines or less.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: What is your current o/p?

Comment: It is fairly obvious - you do *not* send the OS infromation to the server, instead you send an object which dynamically determines the OS by calling `otherInfo`... determine OS on client side and just send the string...

Comment: what should I do now

Comment: current output comes same as on which machine my server module run.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in my comment you must transfer the data, not the function. Some sample code below...

First, change your SI class as follows:

```
public class SI implements Serializable { 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String osName;

    public void setOsName(String osName) { this.osName = osName; }
    public void getOsName() { return this.osName; }
}
```

Second, modify your client to first determine the OS and the build the SI object...

```
...
OperatingSystemMXBean bean = (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory
        .getOperatingSystemMXBean();
String osName=bean.getName();

SI sysinfo = new SI();
sysinfo.setOsName(osName);

...
outputStream.writeObject(sysinfo);
...
```

Third, modify your server accordingly.

Comment: @CHIRAGKULSHRESHTHA: plase accept the answer in case it did solve your problem (on the left hand side at the top of the answer)